# Вопрос к сегодняшнему празднику "Пасха".

Tags: этимология

Существует мнение, что "Иисус - Иесус" - "и есть суть". Что вы думаете по этому поводу? И второе: откуда произошло слово "Пасха"? Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Иисус:
Историческое происхождение имени гораздо более прозаично. Происходит от настоящего имени настоящего человека, ישוע (Йешуа). Имя происходит от ивритского корня ЙША, который встречается во многих библейских именах (сравнить: Исаия) и озночает "спасение". Тот же корень, но другая форма, присудствуют в ивритском имени Иисуса Навина - на иврите его имя читается Йехошуа. Хотя я спокойно отношусь к именам с особыми значениями, я считаю, что "и есть суть" уже что-то совсем надуманное. Ну откуда эти русские слова могли взяться в иврите? Нет, тут язык в другую сторону тёк - из иврита, в греческий, и только потом в русский.

Пасха:
Как известно, православная Пасха празднуется в одно время с иудейской, и это неспроста, ведь исторические события Пасхи происходили во время этого праздника. Имя тоже взято оттуда. На иврите Пасха - פסח (пэсах), от корня ПСХ - миновать, пройти мимо. Изначально имя было дано потому, что карая Египет, Божья кара миновала евреев. Чтобы смерть обошла их дома стороной, они должны были принести в жертву овцу и пометить её кровью свои двери. Когда пришло христианство, оно оставило имя, но пересказало историю на новуй лад: кровь Иисуса избавит человечество от страданий. Здесь с именем похожая история: из иврита оно переходит в греческий, а потом, после крещения Руси, и в русский.